# Sony Xperia SP C5303 not booting into fastboot mode

Tags: fastboot, sony-xperia-sp

Device: Sony Xperia SP C5303.

I turned off the device, then hold volume up key, and plugged the USB cable. But I see no blue light. After a while it goes into charge mode.

What could be the problem?

Some additional information:

I'm on Windows 7, 64 bit. I downloaded this driver
http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/fastboot-driver/
and overwrote the one in

```
c:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\
```